# AngularJS image slider is not working when integrating with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-ui-slider

When I'm integrating any slider or any code to my project code - it doesn't work. However, It works in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sV1xckE7SCyMX9b3dVT0?p=preview). I just have to show it in /Homeview . Even this code is working fine in index.html.

Here is my **Homeview** :

```
<div ng-controller="slideShowController" class="imageslide" ng-switch='slideshow' ng-animate="'animate'">
<div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="1">
    <img src="images/slider_1.jpg">
</div>  
<div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="2">
    <img src="images/slider_1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="3">
    <img src="images/slider_1.jpg">
</div>  
<div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="4">
    <img src="images/slider_1.jpg">dhakjsdhhasd
</div>
```

and  here is my app.js

```js
//Define an angular module for our app
var app = angular.module('blickbeeLite', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

app.controller('demoSwipeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.onSwipeLeft = function(ev) {
      alert('You swiped left!!');
    };
    $scope.onSwipeRight = function(ev) {
      alert('You swiped right!!');
    };
    $scope.onSwipeUp = function(ev) {
      alert('You swiped up!!');
    };
    $scope.onSwipeDown = function(ev) {
      alert('You swiped down!!');
    };
  });

app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http)
{
});

app.config(['$provide', '$routeProvider', function ($provide, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
      })
      .when('/:templateFile', {
        templateUrl: function (param) { return 'views/'+param.templateFile+'.html' }
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

```css
#withinheader {
 width:60%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 100px;
}

.imageslide{
 width:100%;
 height:30%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.imageslide .slider-content {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:30%;
}

.animate-enter,.animate-leave {
 -webkit-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
 -moz-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
 -ms-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
 -o-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
 transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
}

.animate-enter {
 left:100%;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
 left:0;
}

.animate-leave {
 left:0;
}

.animate-leave.animate-leave-active {
 left:-100%;
}
```

```html
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Everything is fine, I'm not getting where I'm going wrong. I tried many times, but every time failed. Sometimes, I also add any code to integrate. Issues always welcome me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like the controller in your homeview is named differently than the one you use in the app.js - slideShowController vs demoSlideController

Comment: Actually, Forgot to add Plunker URL link. Here it is working. http://plnkr.co/edit/sV1xckE7SCyMX9b3dVT0?p=preview
If I add it to index page before declared of Directive. It works fine but it doesn't work and perfectly fits on Homeview where I want to display this Image slider. Thanks alot. Please help me. Issue is not resolved yet.